# Adding product attributes to products when building an eccommerce site from scratch using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to build a fashion ecommerce site from scratch using rails  with basic experiance. What is the best way to add product attributes to products, eg. size/color?

I have attempted to do it by creating the following models based on an example structure found here: http://www.webassist.com/tutorials/Free-eCommerce-MySQL-Database. However I am struggling with the implementation, can anyone please help.

**My models are as follows:**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :product_attributions
    has_many :product_attribute, through: :product_attributions
end

class ProductAttribute < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :product_attributions
    has_many :product, through: :product_attributions
    has_one  :product_attribute_group, through: :product_attributions
end

class ProductAttributeGroup < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :product_attributions
    has_many :product_attribute, through: :product_attributions
end

class ProductAttribution < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :product_attribute
    belongs_to :product_attribute_group
end
```

*Explaination*

ProductAttribute is for listing each attribute eg, s/m/l/red/blue
ProductAttributeGroup is to assign each ProductAttribute to a group eg, size/color

**My schema is as follows:**

```
create_table "product_attribute_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "product_attributes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "product_attributions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "product_attribute_id"
    t.integer  "product_attribute_group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "slug",                        null: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.boolean  "status",      default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what errors you’re receiving or specific challenges you’re running in to? For starters though, any time you use `has_many`, the model that follws should be pluralized.